# Function to calculate the min of a range of cells using if statements in excel

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula, cells

I am trying to calculate the min value for a range of cells.

Cells D3:D153 contain either dry or wet, cells C3:C153 contain a number from 0 to 10.

I would like to calculate the minimum for the cells that are dry and are <=5

```
=MIN(IF(AND(D3:D153="Dry", C3:C153<=5)), C3:C153)
```

I thought the above would work but I end up with function errors.

I also have other columns such as G3:G153 which contain dry or wet and F3:F153 which contains a number from 0 to 10. If I wanted to include this in the original function how would I go about combining it?

Comment: Not programming, should be asked at SuperUser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
{=MIN(IF((D3:D153="Dry")*(C3:C153<=5),C3:C153,11))}
```

When you enter it, use Ctrl+Shift+Enter to get the curly brackets (and make it into an array formula).

**Edit, second part of your question:**

```
{=MIN(IF((D3:D153="dry")*(C3:C153<=5),C3:C153,11),IF((G3:G153="dry")*(F3:F153<=5),F3:F153,11))}
```

Alright!

Comment: Note that if there aren't any that are dry and below 6 this will return 11.

Comment: +1, for the second formula you could omit the two internal MIN functions - the outer one should be sufficient

Comment: I guess this means I should remove the comment about more `MIN`s :(. Haha